# Concat values in linear condition (C Language)

Tags: c, conditional-statements

is possible to use %d to concat a value but in a linear condition?

```
printf("You paid € %.2f, %s",
           price,
           (price > 100 ?
                ("Discount %d", discount)
           :
                "No Discount"));
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried this?  It would be easy enough to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the thing to print in another buffer and print that conditionally.

```
char discount_str[128];
snprintf(discount_str, sizeof(discount_str), "Discount %d", discount);

printf("You paid € %.2f, %s",
           price,
           (price > 100 ?
                discount_str
           :
                "No Discount"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No,
What you could do is print them separately

```
// you could add comment to explain following 3 lines
printf("You paid € %.2f, ", price);
if (price > 100) printf("Discount %d", discount);
else printf("No Discount")
```

and that would be the easiest and prettiest solution